# Count Number of Recurring Events until False in Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala, lag

I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of times a row repeats a value back to back until it becomes false, regardless if it becomes true later on.

Example below is that colours bought and when they are used.
When a colour is bought, i would like to track how times it is used until it is swapped off

The rule is:
Once an item has been purchased, how many times do they use the newly purchased item until they swap off.
For Red's example, he uses it 3 times until he changes and i want to tally just that, even if he returns to it
Green was not used immediately and then has zero uses once purchased.

Example Data

| Order_time | Colour Bought Most Recently | Colour Used | Desired Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Red | 1 |
| 2 | Red | Red | 2 |
| 3 | Red | Red | 3 |
| 4 | Red | Blue | 3 |
| 5 | Red | Red | 3 |
| 1 | Green | Blue | 0 |
| 2 | Green | Red | 0 |
| 3 | Green | Green | 0 |

Thanks in advance

I have attempted to utilise Last_value and lag.
I have also attempted to utilise a join to the table and the min() the first time they column 1 to column 2 do not equal
the main issue is that i am unable or do not know how to select the previous value of the same column

I am thinking mostly similar to excel where the formula is in Column C and i check if Column C previous Row was correct or not.

Comment: last line shouldn't be 1 ? how about line 5 , red is being used , shouldn't it be back to 1?

Comment: well, this is what i would like to see is how i have demonstrated it

I would like to see how many times a person selected a colour UNTIL they change since they purchased it.

Comment: Hi - your last comment is confusing as either the comment from @eshirvana is correct and your table is incorrect or your table is correct and you haven't explained clearly how you are calculating the Desired Result column. If the count starts with 1 whenever the row changes then the last 4 rows should be 1; if the count starts with zero whenever the rows change then the first row should be zero, not 1 (as should row 5). Please can you update your question with a clear, unambiguous, set of rules for how the Desired Result needs to be calculated.

Comment: Also, how are you determining the order of these records - as the records in a table have no intrinsic order? Can you update your question with the DDL for the table(s) involved, please?

Comment: I have included a time frame of the order

Apologies, i will try my best to explain

I am trying to see how many times a colour is used once it is bought. If they use a different colour, the chain is broken and we could how many times the user used the new colour until they changed
In Red's example, he used the bought colour three times until changing. So i would like to show just 3

For Green, once they bought it, they never used it, so the chain is immediately broken and gives 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be able to order the rows via some kind of sequence or time data:

```
with flagged as (
    select *,
        case when bought <> lag(bought, 1, '')
            over (order by order_time) then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from T
), grouped as (
    select *,
        sum(flag) over (order by order_time) as grp
    from flagged
), tallied as (
    select *,
        min(case when bought <> used then 0 else 1 end)
            over (partition by grp order by order_time) as tally
    from grouped
)
select *,
    sum(tally) over (partition by grp order by order_time)
from tallied;
```

Maybe there's a slightly cleaner way but this is a fairly standard gaps and islands technique.

See it in action here: https://dbfiddle.uk/TFFHRLz3

Comment: thank you for this :)

after a bunch of working, this is exactly my approach on this,